# How can I remove blank space at the end of x axes when I use rangeselector in Highchart.stockchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHWy0.png)How can I remove blank space at the end of x axes when I use rangeselector in Highchart.stockchart?
It seems like that blank space gets smaller as I click on 7-day to 3-month button in rangeselector.
When I click on the last option, there's no blank space.

I tried to remove it by adjusting xAxis settings.
(maxPadding: 0, setting endOnTick: false, ordinal: false, max: data's last timestamp)
But none of them worked.
I want to make a chart like this image.

Comment: Use the `.trim()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I don't think it has anything to do with adjusting the spaces or padding at the end of the x-axis of the chart in the space next to xAxis, Highcharts.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, it would help if you included code or a reproducible example of the example you mention, since I see the site you mention actually has them: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/ohlc

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `yAxis.tickAmount` option to achieve that:

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lzj0by4u/
**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.tickAmount